# How to add event to google calendar api without conferencing

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api

By default if you insert event using api with attendees, the conferencing is 'Hangouts Meet' in my case. And I don't want to include a conferencing.

In the api guide, there's a field 'conferenceData' and I don't know how to use it. As you can see in the attached image below.
[image]

Hope someone have an idea about this.
This is my event object:

```
let event = {
    'summary': summary,
    'start': {
        'dateTime': start
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': end
    },
    'attendees': [
        {'email': email},
    ],
    'guestsCanModify': true,
    'conferenceData': {
        createRequest: ''
    }
};
```

Comment: Try removing the 'conferenceData' key from event and create it.

Comment: I already did it. But the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not specify anything in the conferenceData field and at the same time set the conferenceDataVersion=1 on your request.

An example:

```
    POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?conferenceDataVersion=1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2018-12-01T02:00:00Z"
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2018-12-01T00:00:00Z"
 },
 "attendees": [
  {
   "email": "email@email.com"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. It works now. I should add it in request parameters not in request body.